# Modular Inverse in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So far I've solved euclid, lCM,extGCD, and coprime. How would I solve for the modular Inverse(minv)? I think that "assumes a n are coprime" is confusing me.

```
euclid :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
euclid 0 0 = error "GCD(0,0) is undefined"
euclid a 0 = a
euclid a b =  euclid b (a `emod` b)

-- Returns the least common multiple of a and b, using the definition of lcm
-- given in class (in terms of the gcd). DO NOT use the built-in `lcm` function.
lCM :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
lCM 0 0 = error "LCM(0,0) is undefined"
lCM a b = a*b `ediv` (euclid a b)

-- extGCD a b
-- Returns the GCD of a and b, along with x and y such that
--   GCD(a,b) = ax + by
-- calculated via the recursive extended Euclidean algorithm presented in
-- class.
extGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer,Integer,Integer)
extGCD 0 0 = error "extGCD(0,0) is undefined"
extGCD a 0 = (1,0,a)     -- Base case
extGCD a b = let (q,r) = a `eDivMod` b           -- q and r of a/b
               (c,x,y) = extGCD b r          -- Recursive call
         in  (x,c-q*x, y) -- Recursive results

-- coprime a b 
-- Returns True if a and b are coprime (have no common factors)
coprime :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
coprime 0 0 = error "coprime(0,0) is undefined"
coprime a b = (euclid a b) == 1

-- minv a n
-- Returns the modular inverse of a mod n. Assumes that a and n are coprime.
minv :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
minv a n =
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with your `extGCD` function.

If *a* and *m* are co-prime, then use your `extGCD` function to solve:

```
a*x + m*y = gcd a m = 1
```

That means *a* * *x* = 1 mod *m*, i.e. *a* and *x* are multiplicative inverses mod *m*.

Answer (score 3):

First of all `a` and `n` must be coprime because otherwise the inverse doesn't exist. This comes from the fact that finding the inverse of `a` modulo `n` is the same as solving the congruence: `ax = 1 mod n`.

A linear congruence `ax = b mod n` has a solution only if `gcd(a, n) | b`. But in this case `gcd(a, n) | 1` implies that `gcd(a, n) = 1`.

So now, to find the inverse you use Bezout identity, i.e. there exist `x` and `y` such that: `gcd(a, n) = a*x + n*y`. You have already found such values in your `extGCD` function so you can implement `minv` as:

```
minv a n =  a*x + n*y
    (x, y, _) = extGCD a n
```

It may be better to write a function with type `Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer` and return `Nothing` if the `extGCD` is different from `1`:

```
minv a n =
  | g == 1    = Just $ a*x + n*y
  | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    (x, y, g) = extGCD a n
```

---

As an aside: the subgroup of invertible elements in Z<sub>n</sub> is precisely the set of `a`s < `n` coprime with `n`. When `n` is prime this subgroup coincides with Z<sub>n</sub> without `0` and in this case Z<sub>n</sub> is a field.

Answer (score 0):

Bézout's identity states that for any integers `a` and `b`, there exist integers `x` and `y` such that `ax + by = gcd(a, b)` (see [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)). Specifically, when `a` and `b` are co-prime, this simplifies to `ax + by = ax = gcd(a, b) = 1 mod b`. Utilizing the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), we iterate through expressions of the form `(b mod a)x + ay = gcd(a, b)`, where we redefine `a` as `a' = b mod a` and `b` as `b' = a`. Eventually, we arrive at the final state where `(a, b, x, y) = (0, gcd(a, b), 0, 1)`.

To implement this in Haskell, we define a function `extgcd` that takes `a` and `b` as inputs and returns a tuple `(x, y)`. To understand the relationship between each iteration, we compare the equations `ax + by = gcd(a, b)` and `(b mod a)x + ay = gcd(a, b)`. From this comparison, we derive `x = y' - floor(b/a) * x'` and `y = x'`. This leads us to the following Haskell implementation:

```hs
modInverse :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
modInverse a n = case gcd a n of
  1 -> Just $ makePositive $ fst $ extgcd a n
  _ -> Nothing
  where
    extgcd 0 b = (0, 1)
    extgcd a b =
      let (x', y') = extgcd (b `mod` a) a
          x = y' - (b `div` a) * x'
          y = x'
      in (x, y)
    makePositive x = if x >= 0 then x else x + n
```

Comment: https://blog-blockchain.xyz/college-courses/modular-inverses/ details in my blog